# CSS How to position div inside div so that it will always be 100%

Tags: html, css

Using the CSS property 'position', how would it be possible to make a div inside another div always 100% height of the parent div, with a margin of 40px on the top and on the bottom? It needs to be adjusting, so that if the parent div is 700px in height, the child div will be 620px (700px - 80px from margins). Here is an example of what I mean:

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WR5pY.png) the parent div (green) is tall, so the child (orange) must stretch to fit the space.

And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXKRG.png) the parent (green) is squashed, so the child (orange) must compensate by squashing itself to fit.

Thank you in advance.

**Edit:**

Here is the html Im working with:

```
<div id="center-page">
    <p id="center-page-title">Blog</h1>
    <div id="content">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are many possibilities. Pleas share with us that code with which you are working.

Comment: Though slightly undersupported, you could try `height: calc(100%-80px);`.

Comment: @Yemachu This wouldnt work as when height for the child div is set to 100% it takes the 100% from the whole page, not the parent div like I want.

Comment: You have content in your `HTML` code while in your images, I don't see any such content. Its hard to imaging what you wants to achieve.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman I dont have any pictures?

Comment: You can add the pictures you linked to to the post itself, making it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```css
#center-page {
  position: relative;
  background: green;
  height: 700px;
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  background: orange;
  top: 40px;
  bottom: 40px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="center-page">
    <p id="center-page-title">Blog</h1>
    <div id="content">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you dearly.

Comment: You're welcome, then kindly mark this as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try absolute positioning with `top` and `bottom` values. Something like this:

```
#child{
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  bottom: 40px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: blue;
}
```

Here is an example: 
 https://jsfiddle.net/Lys72mgy/